# Docker save only non public layers

Tags: docker

I can export images with

```
docker save -o <save image to path> <image name>
```

but this will pack all layers, and the file is big

is there a possibility to pack only layers which are not public available, so only the difference to the last public layer is exported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docker-save-last-layer](https://github.com/brthor/docker-save-last-layer) command line utility combined with `docker build --squash` is made to accomplish exactly this.

It exports only the last layer of the specified docker image.

It works by using a patched version of the docker daemon inside a docker image that can access the images on your host machine. So it doesn't require doing a full `docker save` before using it like the `undocker` answer. This makes it much more performant for large base images.

Typical usage is simple and looks like:

```
pip install d-save-last

docker build --t myimage --squash .
d-save-last myimage -o ./myimage.tar
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try [undocker](https://github.com/larsks/undocker/). The tool can extract all or part of the layers of a Docker image onto the local filesystem. You can extract one or more specific layers:

```
$ docker save busybox |
  undocker -vi -o busybox -l ea13149945cb6b1e746bf28032f02e9b5a793523481a0a18645fc77ad53c4ea2
INFO:undocker:extracting image busybox (4986bf8c15363d1c5d15512d5266f8777bfba4974ac56e3270e7760f6f0a8125)
INFO:undocker:extracting layer ea13149945cb6b1e746bf28032f02e9b5a793523481a0a18645fc77ad53c4ea2
```

Of course, it doesn't automatically sort out publicly available layers, but this is something you can start with, here is the tool [intro article](http://blog.oddbit.com/2015/02/13/unpacking-docker-images/) by original author.